# Create Hierarchical Array from MySQL result

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I've seen other questions about this but not quite like my situation. I have the following table in MySQL:

```
   term_id       name           slug                 taxonomy     parent
1             Entry Form     entry-form           format       0
2             Page           page                 format       3
3             Facebook       facebook             format       0
4             Entry Form     facebook-entry-form  format       3
5             Twitter        twitter              format       0
6             Single        single                format       2
```

I have the following OBJECT query:

```
$formats = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("
    SELECT * FROM table t
    WHERE t.taxonomy = 'format'
"));
```

I wind up with the following array:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 1 [name] => Entry Form [slug] => entry-form [taxonomy] => format [parent] => 0 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 2 [name] => Page [slug] => page [taxonomy] => format [parent] => 3 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 3 [name] => Facebook [slug] => facebook [taxonomy] => format [parent] => 0 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 4 [name] => Entry Form [slug] => entry-form-facebook [taxonomy] => format [parent] => 3 ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 5 [name] => Twitter [slug] => twitter [taxonomy] => format [parent] => 0 ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 6 [name] => Single [slug] => single [taxonomy] => format [parent] => 2 ) ) 1
```

All of the above needs to be turned into a hierarchical list on output that looks like this:

```
Entry Form
Twitter
Facebook
 - Entry Form
 - Page
 -- Single
```

As such, I need to turn array $formats into a hierarchical array based on the parent field. A parent of 0 means it is a top level item. As such, since Single has parent of 2 it is the child of Page which in turn has parent of 3 and is a child of Facebook.

Can anyone help me turn my array into a hierarchical array and then show me how I can loop through it for output?

Comment: May be you have explained it, but i dont understand what output you want? Can you describe a snippet of output? Do you want only names in hierarchical form or all data?

Comment: I want output to be exactly as described: A hierarchical list. Like <ul>
 <li>Entry Form</li>
 <li>Twitter</li>
 <li>Facebook
<ul>
 <li>Page
<ul>
 <li>Single</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>

Answer (score 0):

If performance due to volume of queries is not going to be a problem, the simplest solution is that, instead of doing a single query that populates an array, you do one query per node in your hierarchical tree, adding a "AND parent = $id", where $id is the term_id of the current node. Something like:

1. Do a SELECT WHERE .... AND parent = 0;
2. for each result in 1, $id = term_id, do a select WHERE ... AND
   parent = $id
3. Repeat recursively until no more results

If performance is a problem you can still dump the query to your array and apply the same algorithm to the array, but you most likely will have memory issues doing it that way if you really have that much volume.

Comment: This strikes me as even more inefficient. Reason being that if the children are 20 layers deep, I shouldn't be running so many queries n the database. Seems like that is wasted bandwidth to me.

Comment: That's why I made the comment about performance and volume of queries. If you have 20 layers deep but not going to be running the algorithm continuously for thousands of users, you'll be fine. But if that's the case, dumping the entire results in an array might get you to out of memory and or pagination problems anyway. The key of the question (and the answer) is the recursive algorithm you need to use.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. I don't know what you mean by recursive though. But I'l look into it.

Comment: Recursive because you create a function that prints an element and its children, and from it you call the same function again for each of the children, so that they can print themselves and their children. If you're not familiar with the concept, look it up, it's a must in programming.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the data into assoc array while fetching it from the database:

```
//$groups - result array

$groups = array();

//$record contains the assoc array of the current record
while($record = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
      if (!isset($groups[$record["parent"]]))
      {
            $groups[$record["parent"]] = array();
      }

      array_push($groups[$record["parent"]], $record);
}
```

In the end you will get an assoc array of hierarchy with parent as a key. Then traverse through it recursively, and you'll get the result:

```
function print_recursively(&$groups, $parent_id, $dashes = '')
{
    if(isset($groups[$parent_id]))
    {
          foreach($groups[$parent_id] as $key => $value)
          {
                print $dashes . ' ' . $value["name"];
                print_recursively(&$groups, $value["term_id"], $dashes . '-');
          }
    }
}
```

I didn't test this code, but the algorithm is correct.

Comment: This whole concept is entirely new to me. I don't even know where to start with this code. I don't recognize any of the variables as being ones I've used. Where would my $formats variable fit into this?

Comment: At first show me the code, where you fetch the data from the database. I'll try to show you, how to modify it.

Comment: The code is right there: $formats = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("
    SELECT * FROM table t
    WHERE t.taxonomy = 'format'
"));

Comment: Can you change the code, so it will get the results sequentially: one row after another?